# I am having this error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ado.net

I am having this error and as a beginner I dont know what appropriate solution should be used.
The following is the controller code

```
public class AdminBlogController : Controller
{
    private readonly BlogDataAccess blogDataAccess;
    private readonly UserDataAccess userDataAccess;
    public AdminBlogController()
    {
         blogDataAccess = new BlogDataAccess();
         userDataAccess = new UserDataAccess(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public ActionResult Post(int id)
    {
         BlogPost blogPost = blogDataAccess.GetBlogPostById(id);

         if (blogPost == null)
         {
              return HttpNotFound();
         }

         return View(blogPost);
    }
}
```

Now I am attaching the view for Post action method from where I am accessing the content for Blog

```
@model List<ChatGptAdoPrac.Models.BlogPost>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Post";
}

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    @*<p hidden>@post.Id</p>*@
    <h2>@post.Title</h2>
    <p>@post.Content</p>
    <p>Published Date: @post.PublishDate</p>
    if (post.Id != null && post.Id.HasValue && post.Id.Value != 0)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Read More", "Post", "Blog", new { id = post.Id.Value }, null)
    }

}
```

Now follwing is the code for Blog Data Access from where I have made connections with database

```
public BlogPost GetBlogPostById(int id)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM BlogPosts WHERE Id = @Id";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                BlogPost post = new BlogPost
                {
                    Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                    Title = (string)reader["Title"],
                    Content = (string)reader["Content"],
                    PublishDate = (DateTime)reader["PublishDate"]
                };

                return post;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now when after running the project,I am clicking on Blog and it is showing this error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Post(Int32)' in 'Project1.Controllers.AdminBlogController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
> Parameter name: parameters

Although in my url link I am only seeing this like id is missing there

`https://localhost:44359/AdminBlog/Post`

As I have said I am beginner and I have checked all the steps but still I have failed to resolve the issue please help me how can I overcome this error.

Comment: why did you use "adminblog" and use instead of "blog" for redirect"    @Html.ActionLink("Read More", "Post", "Blog", new { id = post.Id.Value }, null)"

Comment: Are you using Asp.net mvc or asp.net core? They are different frameworks.